# java- how to add time properly?

Tags: java

My code isn't working properly for example when a user put that right now is 5 h 43 m and 7 s and the user wanna add 3 h 50 m and 57 s the code compute and shows what will be the time adding but it shows 8 h 93 m and 64 s but I want that after 60 m it shows 9 h 34 m and 4 s so can u help me out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
        int startup_hour;
        int startup_minute;
        int startup_second;
    
        int add_hours;
        int add_minutes;
        int add_seconds;
    
        System.out.print("what time is it right now(hour)? \n");
        startup_hour = user_input.nextInt();
    
        System.out.print("what time is it right now(minutes? \n");
        startup_minute = user_input.nextInt();
    
        System.out.print("what time is it right now(seconds)? \n");
        startup_second = user_input.nextInt();
    
    
        System.out.println("The starting time is " + startup_hour
            + " hours " + startup_minute + " minutes " + "and "
            + startup_second + " seconds \n");
    
        System.out.print("How many hours you wanna add? \n");
        add_hours = user_input.nextInt();
    
        System.out.print("How many minutes you wanna add? \n");
        add_minutes = user_input.nextInt();
    
        System.out.print("How many seconds you wanna add? \n");
        add_seconds = user_input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("The user wanna add " + add_hours
            + " hours " + add_minutes + " minutes "
            + "and " + add_seconds + " seconds \n");

        int totalHours = (startup_hour + add_hours);
        int totalMinutes = (startup_minute + add_minutes);
        int totalSeconds = (startup_second + add_seconds);
    
        if (totalSeconds == 60){
            totalMinutes++; 
            totalSeconds = 0;
        }

        if (totalMinutes == 60){
            totalHours++;
            totalMinutes = 0;
        }
    
        System.out.println("After adding, the time would then be "
           + totalHours + " hours " + totalMinutes + " Minutes "
           + totalSeconds + " Seconds ");
    
              *emphasized text*
    }
}
```

thanku

Comment: Side note: read about proper Java code indentation. You should put your { braces at the end of a line, and be consistent about using always the same indentation. Such things matter. They make your code easy to read, or hard to read.

Comment: Think about what will happen if `startup_minute` is 50 and `add_minutes` is 20. What will `totalMinutes` be? What will your `if` statement which compares `totalMinutes` to 60 do? Is there a different comparison operator which would work? If you use that, what else will you need to change?

Comment: If you are not familiar with Java operators, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `LocalDateTime` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html It has all the methods you need for your use case - like `plusHours`, `plusMinutes` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program is not working because **you are processing time, without using the standard unit, which is `seconds`**.

*For example*:

Suppose the start up time is **`1 hours 3 minutes and 57 seconds`**.
And the user want to add, **`1 hour 57 minutes and 3 seconds`**.

The correct answer will be, **`3 hours 1 Minutes 0 Seconds`** but your program will return **`2 hours 61 Minutes 0 Seconds`**.

Now, why did this happen?

The reason are:

- As already stated, you did not process time using the standard unit (`seconds`).
- The condition in your `if` loop is not correct. You are only checking if the `minutes/seconds` are equal to 60. What if the `minutes` or `seconds` are 61 or more?

#### Solution:

> The simplest solution is, first convert time into `seconds`, add how much time you want to add, then convert it back to `hours:minutes:seconds.` You won't even have to use `if` loop if you process time using `seconds`.

Here is the modified code, which works properly :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Test 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int startup_hour;
    int startup_minute;
    int startup_second;
    int add_hours;
    int add_minutes;
    int add_seconds;

    System.out.print("What time is it right now(hour)    : ");
    startup_hour = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What time is it right now(minutes) : ");
    startup_minute = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What time is it right now(seconds) : ");
    startup_second = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The starting time is " + startup_hour + " hours " + startup_minute + " minutes "
            + "and " + startup_second + " seconds.");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("How many hours you wanna add   : ");
    add_hours = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("How many minutes you wanna add : ");
    add_minutes = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("How many seconds you wanna add : ");
    add_seconds = user_input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The user wanna add " + add_hours + " hours " + add_minutes + " minutes "
            + "and " + add_seconds + " seconds.");
    System.out.println();

    int totalSecondsAtStart = (startup_hour * 60 * 60) + (startup_minute * 60) + startup_second;
    int totalSecondsToAdd = (add_hours * 60 * 60) + (add_minutes * 60) + (add_seconds);
    int totalSeconds = totalSecondsAtStart + totalSecondsToAdd;

    //Convert total seconds to hour, minutes and seconds;
    int totalMinutes = (totalSeconds / 60);
    int totalHours = (totalMinutes / 60);

    int finalHours = totalHours;
    int finalMinutes = totalMinutes - (totalHours * 60);
    int finalSeconds = totalSeconds - (totalMinutes * 60);

    System.out.println("After adding, the time would then be " + finalHours + " hours"
      + " " + finalMinutes + " Minutes " + finalSeconds + " Seconds.");
}
}
```

Notice how I converted time back into `hours:minutes:seconds`.